# How to set elevation for pre Lollipop

Tags: android, elevation

> how to set elevation for pre Lollipop and could I make dimension change?

and how to change the dimension of elevation in pre Lollipop?

Comment: Use 9patch image in background to give illusion of shadow.

Comment: Sorry but its not possible for prelollipop.If you wanna to do that using some tricks like 9 patch or custom edittext .

Answer (score 0):

you have to add android support library to your project and use cardview as your parent view in your xml file and add `card_view:cardElevation="2dp"` to it

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/itemCardView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry to say but in material almost many of elevation attr cant be used pre Lollipop but you can use shadow library from github and add it to any View you and again has the minSdk of android 4 but work at pre Lollipop.